# Pass and receive raw byte data via an unsigned char* function parameters in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c, dllimport, unsigned-char

I have a 3rd party x.dll and an export function which is named as "GenerateKeyEx-in C". I do not have any additional info such as .lib, header etc. I have found the function parameters from x.dll supplier and they are already added in the code.

Here you can see the parameter definitions;

```
> [in] ipSeedArray: the seed queried by the ECU (as byte raw data)
> [in] iSeedArraySize: The size of the array
> [in] iSecurityLevel: the security level to be change to
> [in] ipVariant: the ECU variant’s qualifier
> [out] iopKeyArray: the calculated key on return (as byte raw data)
> [in] iMaxKeyArraySize: maximum number of key bytes available
> [out] oActualKeyArraySize: the number of key bytes calculated
```

I can access and run the function "GenerateKeyEx" without any error. Functions returns always 4 which is unspecified error for the function. I think I can not pass the array values(or initialize the arrays correctly) between main and dll function. const unsigned char* ipSeedArray and unsigned char* iopKeyArray are specified as raw data bytes(above) and did I define the arrays wrong to pass raw byte datas via unsigned char* ?

```
//__stdcall replaced  //__cdecl *f_GenerateKey 
typedef int(*f_GenerateKey)(const unsigned char* ipSeedArray,unsigned int iSeedArraySize,const unsigned int iSecurityLevel,
    const char* ipVariant,unsigned char* iopKeyArray,unsigned int iMaxKeyArraySize,unsigned int& oActualKeyArraySize);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\thego\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApplication1cp\\ConsoleApplication1cp\\Debug\\SeednKey.dll");
    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // resolve function address here
    f_GenerateKey GenerateKey = (f_GenerateKey)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "GenerateKeyEx");
    if (!GenerateKey) {
        std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const int sb = 4;  const int kb = 100;
    const BYTE seedbuffer[sb] = { 0x0B,0xCF,0xFE,0x10 };                            //function in                           
    unsigned int seedbufferSize = sizeof(seedbuffer) / sizeof(seedbuffer[0]);   //function in
    const unsigned int SecurityLevel = 0x01;                                    //function in
    const char Variant[1] = { '0' };                                            //function in
    BYTE keybuffer[kb];                                                         //function out
    for (int i = 0; i < kb; ++i) keybuffer[i] = 0x00;
    unsigned int MaxKeykeybuffer = sizeof(keybuffer) / sizeof(keybuffer[0]);    //function in
    unsigned int oSize;                                                     //function out

    int x = GenerateKey(seedbuffer, seedbufferSize, SecurityLevel, Variant, keybuffer, MaxKeykeybuffer, oSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the shown "parameter definitions" is all the provider of the DLL is giving you, then either they should be removed as suppliers, or they need to be forced to provide actual function declarations with *exact* types, as well as "error" return codes.

Comment: You are right :) What is the best way to pass byte raw data to and from a function via  unsigned char* parameters?

Comment: I am using the dll which contains GenerateKeyEx function and it has different parameters. I also checked it via dll viewer. You can find the function defition here [link](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-IDG-1-017_SecurityAccess.pdf)    @Hans Passant

Comment: Why don't you get a header file? Are you reverse engineering? And if so, isn't this question just a load of guesswork?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
GenerateKey(seedbuffer, SeedArraySize, ...
```

you are using `seedbuffer`, while (I'm guessing) you need `SeedArray`.

The bottom line is: you are passing an array of 4 bytes, and tell them that there are 9.

Comment: I have updated the code, sorry for unnecessary part. SeedArray was not used in the function call.

Comment: @Katsazuka I found the code that is suspiciously similar to your DLL in question: https://github.com/skysky97/seed_to_key/blob/master/algorithm/algorithm.cpp It always returns `0`. You have this comment in your code: `//__stdcall replaced  //__cdecl *f_GenerateKey ` - are you not sure what the calling convention is?

Comment: @Katsazuka - just FYI: your code runs fine against that DLL in my previous comment ^^

Comment: I checked the code you sent above. I can call the function in that code and create the key without any issue with the exactly same parameters which I used for dll function. That is why I could not understand the problem of dll function.